# Only update specific values using updateOne $set in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to only update two values inside todo in the Mongoose model below

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    phone: Number,
    points: Number,
    todo: {

    }
})
```

The todo actually contains 11 values and I only want to update 2 values at a time which I am getting from the frontend

```js
let {
    t,
    i
} = req.body.delitem;
await User.updateOne({
    username: req.body.user
}, {
    $set: {
        todo: {
            [t]: "",
            [i]: ""
        }
    }
})
```

but what is happening is these two fields are getting set to blank strings but the remaining fields are also changing to `NULL` whereas I want the other fields to stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use dot notation like this:

```
await User.updateOne({username:req.body.user},
{
  "$set": {
    "todo.t": "",
    "todo.i": ""
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JwPm7WWtvgI)

If you use an object into `$set` you are telling mongo to replace the object by the new one.

Comment: Yeah actually its updating the values correctly, but it is making new fields named i and t, if I use `"todo.[i]"`, still it is making a new field named [i]. It should change dynamically on the given situations. Real fields are like t1,t2.... similarly i1,i2...

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that you're using $set and passing a whole object which overwrites the whole todo with your `t` and `i` fields and you've enforced required on those other fields.

[If you see the docs](http://This%20means%20that%20any%20callback%20that%27s%20pending,%20any%20network%20request%20still%20being%20sent,%20any%20filesystem%20access,%20or%20processes%20writing%20to%20stdout%20or%20stderr%20-%20all%20is%20going%20to%20be%20ungracefully%20terminated%20right%20away.) in mongo for $set you can instead update specific fields in subobjects. The following snippet should be more appropriate.

```
let {t,i} = req.body.delitem;
await User.updateOne({username:req.body.user}, {
  $set: { 
    "todo.t": "",
    "todo.i": ""
  }
})
```

Comment: Yeah actually its updating the values correctly, but it is making new fields named i and t, if I use "todo.[i]", still it is making a new field named [i]. It should change dynamically on the given situations. Real fields are like t1,t2.... similarly i1,i2...